# Radius loadbalancing using nginx

Tags: nginx, radius

I am trying to loadbalance radius traffic using nginx. For the scenario I have two servers running seagull radius server/client.

Now I put a raspberry-pi running nginx as loadbalnacer in the middle. So my seagull-redius client calls to raspberry-pi's open port and nginx redirect it to seagull-redius server.

My `nginx.conf` in raspberry-pi

```
stream {
  upstream syslog_udp {
    server 123.456.789.1:1813;
  }
  server {
    listen 1800 udp;
    proxy_pass syslog_udp;
    proxy_responses 0;
  }
}
```

I open port 1800 using `sudo nc -lk 1800`
When I run seagull-radius client, I get some gibberish output on raspberry console. but packets are not redirected to seagull server.

How can I perform this properly?
seagull-radius client/server example work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer for this. There are some modifications to be done in both nginx configuration and seagull client/server sides to send UDP packets (Radius).

First Seagull client should have

```
<define entity="transport"
    name="trans-ip-v4"
    file="libtrans_ip.so"
    create_function="create_cipio_instance"
    delete_function="delete_cipio_instance"
    init-args="type=udp">
  </define>

  <define entity="channel"
    name="trans-ip-v4"
    protocol="radius-accounting-v1"
    transport="trans-ip-v4"
    open-args="mode=client;dest=123.456.789.50:1800;source=123.456.789.100">
  </define>
```

Here very important part is `source=123.456.789.100`, this is missing in official seagull radius guide. This is seagull radius client server.

Server side only have to change `init-args="type=udp` from `tcp`:

```
<define entity="transport"
    name="trans-ip-v4"
    file="libtrans_ip.so"
    create_function="create_cipio_instance"
    delete_function="delete_cipio_instance"
    init-args="type=udp">
  </define>
```

In raspberry pi port should open as `sudo nc -lku 1800`, its IP address `123.456.789.50`

In `nginx.conf`

```
stream{
    upstream radius_loadbalance{
        server 123.456.789.1:1813;
        server 123.456.789.2:1813;
    }

    server {
        listen 1800 udp;
        proxy_pass radius_loadbalance;
        proxy_responses 1;
        #error_log logs/radius_lb.log;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone in future.

Comment: i don't see how this is loadbalancing anything.  you have one nginx, one radius.   it's merely proxied.

Comment: @MarkLybarger Sorry, it was my mistake. I have updated the answer. This was tested and verified using `tcpdumps`.